# MatLab code speed and optimization. How to improve?

Tags: performance, matlab, function, optimization, plot

Could someone please run this for me and tell me how long it takes for you? It took my laptop 60s. I can't tell if it's my laptop that's crappy or my code. Probably both.
I just started learning MatLab, so I'm not yet familiar with which functions are better than others for specific tasks. If you have any suggestions on how I could improve this code, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
function gbp
clear; clc;

zi = 0;                                  % initial position
zf = 100;                                % final position

Ei = 1;                                  % initial electric field
c = 3*10^8;                              % speed of light
epsilon = 8.86*10^-12;                   % permittivity of free space
lambda = 1064*10^-9;                     % wavelength
k = 2*pi/lambda;                         % wave number
wi = 1.78*10^-3;                         % initial waist width (minimum spot size)
zr = (pi*wi^2)/lambda;                   % Rayleigh range
Ri = zi + zr^2/zi;                       % initial radius of curvature
qi = 1/(1/Ri-1i*lambda/(pi*wi^2));       % initial complex beam parameter
Psii = atan(real(qi)/imag(qi));          % Gouy phase
mat = [1 zf; 0 1];                       % transformation matrix

A = mat(1,1); B = mat(1,2); C = mat(2,1); D = mat(2,2);
qf = (A*qi + B)/(C*qi + D);              % final complex beam parameter
wf = sqrt(-lambda/pi*(1/imag(1/qf)));    % final spot size
Rf = 1/real(1/qf);                       % final radius of curvature
Psif = atan(real(qf)/imag(qf));          % final Gouy phase

% Hermite - Gaussian modes function
u = @(z, x, n, w, R, Psi) (2/pi)^(1/4)*sqrt(exp(1i*(2*n+1)*Psi)/(2^n*factorial(n)*w))*...
            hermiteH(n,sqrt(2)*x/w).*exp(-x.^2*(1/w^2+1i*k/(2*R))-1i*k*z);

% Complex amplitude coefficients function
a = @(n) exp(1i*k*zi)*integral(@(x) Ei.*conj(u(zi, x, n, wi, Ri, Psii)),-2*wi,2*wi);

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
xlisti = -0.1:1/10000:0.1;              % initial x-axis range
xlistf = -0.1:1/10000:0.1;              % final x-axis range
nlist = 0:2:20;                         % modes range

     function Eiplot
        Efieldi = zeros(size(xlisti));
        for nr = nlist
            Efieldi = Efieldi + a(nr).*u(zi, xlisti, nr, wi, Ri, Psii)*exp(-1i*k*zi);
        end
        Ii = 1/2*c*epsilon*arrayfun(@(x)x.*conj(x),Efieldi);
    end

    function Efplot
        Efieldf = zeros(size(xlistf));
        for nr = nlist
            Efieldf = Efieldf + a(nr).*u(zf, xlistf, nr, wf, Rf, Psif)*exp(-1i*k*zf);
        end
        If = 1/2*c*epsilon*arrayfun(@(x)x.*conj(x),Efieldf);
    end

Eiplot
Efplot

plot(xlisti,real(Ii),xlistf,real(If))

xlabel('x(m)')                       % x-axis label
ylabel('I(W/m^2)')                   % y-axis label
end
```

Comment: 23.91 secs here.. maybe crappy too but less crappy maybe :0....

Comment: And i didnt realize if it was sending you data about my credit cards database, so i should be aware in the future about these requests lol...

Comment: haha, interesting and very valid point! XD

Comment: I've found there are several arrayfun calls and symbolics.. Which could be crappy or not. If you are not seeking to embedding or recompiling this code, i would live happily with it. Good work...

Comment: By the way, if you indeed are looking to reduce the time to, lets say 10 times, just keep the talk and lets work on that.....

Comment: I would really like to reduce the time, yes :] Feel free to post an answer so I can give brownie points!

Comment: Minor things. Calling `clear` at the beginning of a function does absolutely nothing (other than slow things down). Your anonymous function `u` has many more input arguments than they really need – use closures (i.e., [variables already defined in the workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-71621)).

Comment: For such activity, i think i will require you buying me a beer, haha...

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code yet? Type help profile to get info about that.

Comment: @Tony i think i did ... when I clicked "Run and Time" it came up with a profile. But I don't really know what I'm looking at. Says "mupadmex" has 50500 calls and take 53 seconds. What is that?

Comment: @Solarmew The report will let you click to find the calling function, but mupadmex is a mex (precompiled function) called by one of the toolbox functions.  If you can reduce the number of calls to this function, you can speed it up, or if you can change the arguments to reduce the complexity.  I don't have the symbolic toolbox, so that's all I can offer.

Comment: @Tony, I'm not sure how to go about reducing the calls. But thank you for you feedback, i'll look into it.

Comment: Typically when you are having performance issues in MATLAB, loops are the common culprit.  I would try and rewrite your two for loops in terms of matrix operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost is coming from the calls to `hermiteH` -- for every call, this creates a new function using symbolic variables, then evaluates the function at your input. The key to speeding this up is to pre-compute the hermite polynomial functions then evaluate those rather than create them from scratch each time (speedup from ~26 seconds to around 0.75 secs on my computer).

With the changes:

```
function gbp

x = sym('x');

zi = 0;                                  % initial position
zf = 100;                                % final position

Ei = 1;                                  % initial electric field
c = 3*10^8;                              % speed of light
epsilon = 8.86*10^-12;                   % permittivity of free space
lambda = 1064*10^-9;                     % wavelength
k = 2*pi/lambda;                         % wave number
wi = 1.78*10^-3;                         % initial waist width (minimum spot size)
zr = (pi*wi^2)/lambda;                   % Rayleigh range
Ri = zi + zr^2/zi;                       % initial radius of curvature
qi = 1/(1/Ri-1i*lambda/(pi*wi^2));       % initial complex beam parameter
Psii = atan(real(qi)/imag(qi));          % Gouy phase
mat = [1 zf; 0 1];                       % transformation matrix

A = mat(1,1); B = mat(1,2); C = mat(2,1); D = mat(2,2);
qf = (A*qi + B)/(C*qi + D);              % final complex beam parameter
wf = sqrt(-lambda/pi*(1/imag(1/qf)));    % final spot size
Rf = 1/real(1/qf);                       % final radius of curvature
Psif = atan(real(qf)/imag(qf));          % final Gouy phase


% Hermite - Gaussian modes function
nlist = 0:2:20;     % modes range

% precompute hermite polynomials for nlist
hermites = {};
for n = nlist
    if n == 0
        hermites{n + 1} = @(x)1.0;
    else
        hermites{n + 1} = matlabFunction(hermiteH(n, x));
    end
end

u = @(z, x, n, w, R, Psi) (2/pi)^(1/4)*sqrt(exp(1i*(2*n+1)*Psi)/(2^n*factorial(n)*w))*...
            hermites{n + 1}(sqrt(2)*x/w).*exp(-x.^2*(1/w^2+1i*k/(2*R))-1i*k*z);

% Complex amplitude coefficients function
a = @(n) exp(1i*k*zi)*integral(@(x) Ei.*conj(u(zi, x, n, wi, Ri, Psii)),-2*wi,2*wi);

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
xlisti = -0.1:1/10000:0.1;              % initial x-axis range
xlistf = -0.1:1/10000:0.1;              % final x-axis range

     function Eiplot
        Efieldi = zeros(size(xlisti));
        for nr = nlist
            Efieldi = Efieldi + a(nr).*u(zi, xlisti, nr, wi, Ri, Psii)*exp(-1i*k*zi);
        end
        Ii = 1/2*c*epsilon*arrayfun(@(x)x.*conj(x),Efieldi);
    end


    function Efplot
        Efieldf = zeros(size(xlistf));
        for nr = nlist
            Efieldf = Efieldf + a(nr).*u(zf, xlistf, nr, wf, Rf, Psif)*exp(-1i*k*zf);
        end
        If = 1/2*c*epsilon*arrayfun(@(x)x.*conj(x),Efieldf);
    end

Eiplot
Efplot

plot(xlisti,real(Ii),xlistf,real(If))

xlabel('x(m)')                       % x-axis label
ylabel('I(W/m^2)')                   % y-axis label
end
```